# Open Layer ( Geoserver ) Spatial Search not working

Tags: gis, openlayers, geospatial, geoserver, ol3-google-maps

I'm getting Exception when doing a **spatial search** from the open layer map ( OL3 )

Here is the **post-call** I'm making to WFS ( Geoserver )
URL **http://xyz:5002/geoserver/wfs**

In Form Data we are sending query parameters

**cql_filter** : INTERSECTS(geometry,POLYGON((13.222566632788059 78.15759658813475,13.201844057837434 78.15141677856444,13.211202857957346 78.17956924438474,13.222900853445154 78.17888259887692,13.222566632788059 78.15759658813475)))

**service** : WFS

**request** : GetFeature

**version** :1.1.0

**typename** : layerName

**outputFormat** : json

**srsname** : EPSG:3857

**Exception I'm Getting**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://xyz:5002/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
        <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.NullPointerException</ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

**Log i got from Geoserver**

```
2022-01-26 14:13:02,585 INFO [geoserver.logging] - Suppressing StdOut logging.  If you want to see GeoServer logs, be sure to look in '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/logs/geoserver.log'
2022-01-26 14:13:52,568 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:372)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Geoserver I'm using 2.20.2**

Can anyone please let me know what is the mistake I'm doing when I doing the spatial search query

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: The most likely issue is that GeoServer WFS expects an XML payload as described in the WFS spec not a form encoded one.

Comment: and don't use such an old version of GeoServer - 2.20.2 is out now

Comment: Thanks, Ian Turton , i added logs and i changed the Geoserver version to 2.20.2

Comment: @IanTurton do you know why this issue coming by seeing the logs?

Comment: you are sending form encoded data instead of XML

Comment: after changing form-encoded data now I'm getting new error \n :::

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon.getExteriorRing()Lorg/locationtech/jts/geom/LineString;
org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon.getExteriorRing()Lorg/locationtech/jts/geom/LineString;

Comment: please [edit] your question with the details of what you are sending and what the log file shows

Comment: Log added in the answer section

Comment: I'm feeling something wrong in the  cql_filter