# Open Layer ( Geoserver ) Spatial Search not returning any features

Tags: gis, openlayers, geoserver, ol3-google-maps

I Created one generic layer in the GeoServer for the open layer ( OL3)  and add a few features in the same layer, I'm trying to do the **spatial search** but the call is **not returning any features**.

Here is the post-call I'm making to WFS ( Geoserver ) URL http://xyz:5002/geoserver/wfs

In Form Data we are sending query parameter

**cql_filter** : INTERSECTS(geometry,POLYGON((13.222566632788059 78.15759658813475,13.201844057837434 78.15141677856444,13.211202857957346 78.17956924438474,13.222900853445154 78.17888259887692,13.222566632788059 78.15759658813475)))

**service** : WFS

**request** : GetFeature

**version** :1.1.0

**typename** : layerName

**outputFormat** : json

**srsname** : EPSG:4326

---

**The result I'm getting**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
    "totalFeatures": 0,
    "numberMatched": 0,
    "numberReturned": 0,
    "timeStamp": "2022-02-03T09:23:51.415Z",
    "crs": null
}
```

**Geoserver I'm using 2.20.2**

Can anyone please let me know what is the mistake I'm doing when I doing the spatial search query

Comment: Your SRS is EPSG:3857 but the filter coordinates look like EPSG:4326

Comment: even if change to 4326 its not working

Comment: as I said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847313/open-layer-geoserver-spatial-search-not-working don't use form data you need to use get with KVP or POST with XML data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Layer ( Geoserver ) Spatial Search not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847313/open-layer-geoserver-spatial-search-not-working)

Comment: I tried with XML payload in post method still same issue not getting empty features

Comment: please [edit] your question with the corrected payload and the response from the server, and the relevant part of the log file

Comment: when the layer data is stored in the PostGIS ( Postgres)  CQL_FILTER is working
but is when the layer is connected HANA DB CQL_FILTER is not working.
connector I'm using to connect HANA DB is ( GT-JDBC-Hana 26.1.06 )

Comment: that is important information that needs to be in the question! Seems like a bug in the HANA module, try contacting SAP